# Targetting a specific Mobile page in wordpress back end

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Im trying to change the back ground for a specific post on a mobile wordpress page.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 940px)
#page {
max-width: 768px;
width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
  background: #007A52;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
}
```

I know page id is used but im not sure how?

Comment: can you share the wordpress page URL. so that we can see which classes are used in that particular theme.

Comment: http://www.thedoughbros.ie/menu/ this is the url I want the colour to be the same on a mobile, the rest of the site has a green background

Answer (score 0):

http://www.thedoughbros.ie/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css

The file above has the following CSS and custom backgrounds for certain posts.

806 represents the post-id so if you want custom backgrounds just keep adding new blocks with different id

```
@media screen and (max-width: 940px) page.custom-background.page-id-806


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
Custom Backgrounds
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
body.custom-background.page-id-806  {
 background-image: url( http://www.thedoughbros.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/menubackground.fw_.png);   
}

body.custom-background.page-id-723  {
 background-image: url(http://thedoughbros.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/VAN3.fw_.png);    
}

body.custom-background.page-id-822  {
 background-image: url(http://thedoughbros.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Restaurant3.fw_.png);    
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 940px) page.custom-background.page-id-806   {
 background: #fff !important;    
}    

body.custom-background.page-id-346  {
 background-image: url(http://thedoughbros.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/14jun.fw_.png);   
}
```

Just add new blocks of CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 940px) page.custom-background.page-id-807   {
 background: #fff !important;    
}

@media screen and (max-width: 940px) page.custom-background.page-id-808   {
 background: #fff !important;    
}

@media screen and (max-width: 940px) page.custom-background.page-id-809   {
 background: #fff !important;    
}
```

Or multiple

```
@media screen and (max-width: 940px) page.custom-background.page-id-807, page.custom-background.page-id-808, page.custom-background.page-id-809, page.custom-background.page-id-810   {
 background: #fff !important;    
}
```